# Why does the initialValue of formik remove when typing on the text input?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have module where need to upload different categories and each category has a initial data of cat_name and cat_image. I used formik form for helping us getting the values easily. Now the main problem that I encounter today is when I type my cat_name the cat_image is removed on the initialValues. I will share to you guys my sample illustration, the image on index (1) is removed when I type on the cat_name.

Illustration:

[image: Image removed itself when I type on the input text]

Here is my formik form:

```
  <Formik
    enableReinitialize
    initialValues={{ 
        initialCategory:[
            {
                cat_image:undefined,
                cat_name: ''
            }
        ] 
    }}
    onSubmit={values =>
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
    }
    
>
    {({ values,handleChange,setFieldValue, setValues }) => (
        <Form>
            <FieldArray
                name="initialCategory"
                render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                    <div>
                        {values.initialCategory && values.initialCategory.length > 0 ? (
                            values.initialCategory.map((categorie, index) => (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <Grid  container alignItems="center" direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                                        <Grid item xs={1} sx={{ mt: 0 }}>
                                            <Button
                                                style={{
                                                    color: '#3167E9', fontSize: 13,
                                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                                    textTransform: 'none', backgroundColor: '#C4C4C4',
                                                    alignItems: 'center', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    height: 65, width: 65, borderRadius: '50%',
                                                    boxShadow: 'none'
                                                }}
                                                variant="contained"
                                                component="label"
                                            >
                                                
                                                {
                                                    
                                                    <img src={categorie.cat_image} style={{ height: 65, width: 65, borderRadius: '50%' }}
                                                    />
                                                }

                                                <input type="file" 
                                                hidden
                                                accept='image/*'
                                                name={`initialCategory[${index}].cat_image`}  
                                                onChange={(e) => {
                                                    const fileReader = new FileReader();
                                                    fileReader.onload = () => {
                                                        if (fileReader.readyState === 2) {
                                                            setFieldValue(`initialCategory[${index}].cat_image`, fileReader.result);
                                                        }
                                                    };
                                                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                                                }}></input>


                                                
                                            </Button>
                                            
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item xs={9}>
                                            <TextField 
                                                onChange={handleChange}  
                                                name={`initialCategory[${index}].cat_name`}  fullWidth />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item >
                                            <img src="/assets/icons/EkisIcon.png" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} style={{ width: 18 }} />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </div>
                            ))
                            
                        ) : (
                            <></>
                        )}
                        
                        <Grid item sx={{ mt: 2 }} container direction="row" justifyContent="flex-end">
                            <Button type="button" variant="contained" onClick={() =>
                            arrayHelpers.push(values.initialCategory,{
                                cat_image:undefined,
                                cat_name: ''
                            })
                            } style={{
                                color: '#3167E9', color: 'white',
                                fontSize: 19, fontWeight: '700', background: 'none', boxShadow: 'none', textTransform: 'none',
                                borderRadius: '0', color: '#000000'
                            }}><img src="/assets/icons/PlusIcon.png" style={{ width: 18 }} /> &nbsp; Add</Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <div>
                            <Grid sx={{ mt: 3 }} direction="row" spacing={1} container justifyContent="space-between" >
                                <Grid container xs={6} item >
                                    <Button  fullWidth variant="outlined" style={{ color: '#3167E9', border: '2px solid #3167E9', borderRadius: '5px', fontSize: 19, fontWeight: '700', textTransform: 'none', borderRadius: '0', height: 50 }}>Cancel</Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid container xs={6} item>
                                    <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" style={{ color: '#3167E9', fontSize: 19, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', textTransform: 'none', borderRadius: '0', height: 50 }}>Save</Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            />
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Advance Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You change state is wrong. [Read more.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
You can try this code:

```
setFieldValue((prev) => {
  return {
    initialCategory: [{ ...prev.initialCategory[index], cat_name: "value" }]
  };
})
```